# How should I add Try & except Block to handle in my for loop

Tags: python, python-3.8

```
        # This is a guess the number game.
        import random

        print ('Hello, What is your name?')
        name = input()

        print('Well, ' + name + '! I am thinking of a number between 1 to 20.') 
        secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)
        print('Debug:' + str(secretNumber))

        for guessTaken in range (1,7):
            print('Take a guess. '+ name +'!' )
            guess =int(input())


            if guess<secretNumber:
                print('Your guess is too low')
            elif guess>secretNumber:
                print('Your guess is too high')
            else:
                break # This is for correct guess is equal.

        if guess ==secretNumber:
            print('Good Job, ' +name+ '! You guess my number in ' + str(guessTaken)+ ' guesses!')
        else:
            print('Nope, The number I was thinking of was ' +str(secretNumber))
```

Hi my fellow super coders,

So I am trying to put Try and Except block in this program, I try it putting just after
guess=int(input())  unfortunately i am not able to make it work.

So i am trying to handle the ValueError, So lets say user needs to input Integers (Numbers), If he types  string like , "One","Six" etc. the program crashes. I want to handle this case. Please can some help me out. :)

Thank You so much.
Cobra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user enters something that is not a number python will skip to the exception because an error will occur, I added some text to the prints to clarify the rules of the game. 
I used else after for loop which is very useful sometimes for the case where the user can't guess the number in 7 tries you can test it and see that even though the else is not after the if, when the if guess==secretNumber is true and you break the loop the else statement is not doing anything. 
P.S still new to answering here so please give feedback about my answer

```
import random

print ('Hello, What is your name?')
name = input()

print('Well, ' + name + '! I am thinking of a number between 1 to 20.') 
secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)
print('Debug:' + str(secretNumber))

for guessTaken in range (1,7):
    print('Take a guess. '+ name +'!, You Have 7 tries'  )
    try:
        guess = int(input())
        if guess<secretNumber :
            print('Your guess is too low')
        elif guess>secretNumber : 
            print('Your guess is too high')
        if guess == secretNumber:
            print('Good Job, ' + name + '! You guess my number in ' + str(guessTaken)+ ' guesses!')
            break # This is for correct guess is equal.
    except:
        print('Please Enter A number ' + name + 'and not anything else' )


else:
    print('Nope, The number I was thinking of was ' +str(secretNumber))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, it re asks if the user inputs a string:

```
        # This is a guess the number game.
        import random

        print ('Hello, What is your name?')
        name = input()

        print('Well, ' + name + '! I am thinking of a number between 1 to 20.') 
        secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)
        print('Debug:' + str(secretNumber))

        for guessTaken in range (1,7):
            print('Take a guess. '+ name +'!' )
            try:
               guess =int(input())
            except:
               print("Must be a number, try again: ")
               continue

            if guess<secretNumber:
                print('Your guess is too low')
            elif guess>secretNumber:
                print('Your guess is too high')
            else:
                break # This is for correct guess is equal.

        if guess ==secretNumber:
            print('Good Job, ' +name+ '! You guess my number in ' + str(guessTaken)+ ' guesses!')
        else:
            print('Nope, The number I was thinking of was ' +str(secretNumber))
```